# Why did David Bowie never play any songs from Labyrinth live?

Tags: rock

I'm a fan of David Bowie and I thought he was excellent in the 1980s movie, Labyrinth. I also liked a lot of the music from that movie, which Bowie wrote the soundtrack to. However, apparently he never played any of the songs from Labyrinth live (not even a 'medley'). I'm wondering if anyone knows why that is and whether he made any known statements about it?