# Why are most songs made for movies not played live?

Tags: soundtrack, live-music

I'm new to the site, and recently came across [this post](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/9815/why-did-david-bowie-never-play-any-songs-from-labyrinth-live) asking why David Bowie has never played any of the songs from the Labyrinth soundtrack, live in concert:

> However, apparently he never played any of the songs from Labyrinth live (not even a 'medley').

It made me curious, and I began searching for answers; and, like others before me, I failed to come up with an explanation outside of my own inference that soundtracks simply aren't played in live concert. However, is that really true? I changed my search terms and still came up empty handed, outside of live movie showings where the soundtrack is played live by an orchestra.

Unsatisfied, I once again changed my search terms, with focus on more recent movies such as Home and Wreck it Ralph. While titles such as "*[Towards the Sun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3jq77_P-cA)*", "*[Dancing in the Dark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLpVrkvrsyk)*", and "*[Red Balloon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3STjfd51Fus)*" didn't yield results, the title "*Shut Up and Drive*" was played live in Milan:

This shows that songs from movies *can* be played live, but they seem to be pretty selective, and as a result, scarce.

---

Why does it seem that most songs made for movies are not played live?

Comment: It could be as simple as licensing.  They may not have the rights to play them.